# check ping for multiple servers - powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

[how to check variables in each line of the text area and test them for ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1dJu.png)

```
foreach ($textbox1 in $textbox1) {

    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $textbox1 -Count 2 -Quiet)
    {
        $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\ping.txt";
        "$textbox1 is Pinging " | fl > $path; notepad $path;

    }
    else
    {
        $path = "$([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop"))\notping.txt";
        "$textbox1 not pinging" | fl > $path; notepad $path;

    }
}
```

> I want to check for each variable in text area individually and check them each whether it pings or not

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is, do you have a question?

Comment: @nkasco I have a textbox i want to enter list of computers in it and check if its able to ping or not ... i think we can use foreach loop here pls advise

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I will use an example of getting the content from a text file:

```
$Servers = gc "(path to txt file, 1 server per line)"

foreach($Server in $Servers){
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet) {    
        Write-Host "$Server is Pinging "    
    } else {
        Write-Host "$Server not pinging"    
    }
}
```

Comment: however this will get input from the text file
i have a textbox were user will enter computer name to check ping stats

'foreach ($textbox1 in $textbox1) {
  
  if (test-Connection -ComputerName $textbox1 -Count 2 -Quiet)
  {
   
   "$textbox1 is Pinging "
   
  }
  else
  {
   "$textbox1 not pinging"
   
  }
 }'

Comment: If you aren't even familiar with the foreach function (which was not used properly in your example btw) then I highly advise against this, as you are not ready to start trying to build GUI type tools. Stick to console for now or as I suggested import from a txt file. Try `$computer = read-host "Enter a computer to ping"`

Comment: this is why im here to get help from experts..  i can do this thru console.. if you can help pls do it..

Comment: @esperento57 pls check

Comment: This is not a "do it for me" site. This is a site that will help you troubleshoot code that is not working. If you haven't even made an attempt to write code to generate a textbox you will not find someone here to do it for you.